# Jquery : Input Search DataTable not filtering

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have simple table , and inside table i have some data to testing the DataTable. I set false to **bFilter** to hide the original search DataTable , and make my own.

The problem is , my own input Text not filtering data in table. Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274028/changing-dom-element-position-of-searchbox-in-datatables), I already to create like this in Jquery.

#### Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var table = $("#data-table").DataTable({
    bSort: true,
    bFilter: false,
    iDisplayStart: 0,
    iDisplayLength: 20,
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    sDom: "Rfrtlip",
  });
  $("#searchFilter").keyup(function () {
    table.search($(this).val()).draw();
  });
});
```

But input Text won't filtering , i missed somewhere ?
[image]

## Table

```
 <input type=\"text\" id=\"searchFilter\" name=\"searchFilter\" placeholder=\"Search...\" style=\"width:200px;\"/>  
 <table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"stdtable \" id=\"data-table\">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>NO</th>
                        <th>JUDUL</th>
                        <th>TANGGAL</th>
                        <th>RINGKASAN</th>
                        <th>STATUS</th>
                        <th>KONTROL</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>zazaza</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                        <td>asdsada</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                        <td>remoremoreo</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search isn't working because you set the option `bFilter: false`. You find more informations about [bFilter here](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features) and about [search() here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()).

I can show you a working example here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $("#data-table").DataTable({
    bSort: true,
    // bFilter: false,
    iDisplayStart: 0,
    iDisplayLength: 20,
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    sDom: "Rfrtlip",
  });

  $('#searchFilter').on('keyup', function() {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" placeholder="Search..." style="width:200px;" />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>JUDUL</th>
      <th>TANGGAL</th>
      <th>RINGKASAN</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
      <th>KONTROL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>zazaza</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
      <td>remoremoreo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```